# Validate textBox text of a float type

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my mysql DB a column type is float(9,3) and in application I need to validate the textbox whether the value is valid for that type or not. How we can validate this.

For eg: if I enter 12345/123456/... it will inserted successfully but if I enter like 1234567 it will throw error. Likewise I need to  check the entire validation.

Thanks.

Comment: look into RegularExpressionValidator it will save you a lot of time..

Comment: whats the correct regular expression for this?

Comment: take a look at mhasan answer below he has specified the regular expression use it in your regular expression validator.

Comment: plz check the comments I added for that answer

Answer (score 0):

for this i would suggest that you should use [MaskedEdit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) control.

You can see a demo [HERE](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo)

Answer (score 0):

You can validate using javascript

//Javascript function:

```
function validate()
{
    var txttext=document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
    var decimal_regex = ^\d{1,6}\.\d{3}$;
    alert(decimal_regex.test(txttext));
}


<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="javascript:return validate();"/>
```

`d{1,6}` restricts that input can have one to six digits before decimal point.

`d{3}` restricts input must have three digits after decimal point

Comment: this will only check whether the number is float or not. I need to restrict with float(9,3) also. what all values accept for float(9,3) I need to accept.

Comment: :( this is not the req. for float(9,3) it will accept 12,123, 21, 1234,...upto 6 digit whole number and decimal digits as well

Comment: so what do you require ,please specify more

Comment: i need to allow the user to only type values that are acceptable by float(9,3)

Answer (score 0):

For your case of 0-3 digits before dot and 0-2 after dot:

[-+]?[0-9]{0,3}.?[0-9]{1,2}